# Laravel Mix does not emit css

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-mix

My Laravel project is not compiling CSS files. I did a fresh install of Laravel with `laravel new project,` then I ran `npm install` and `npm run dev.`

The result I get is:

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 7112ms                                                                        

     Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/js/app.js  1.6 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
```

The /css/app.css is missing in the list and app.css is not emitted.

By running `npm run watch` (or watch-poll/hot), any changes made in app.scss is watched, and the building process is rerun. However, the result is the same - no app.css in the list of compiled files and no app.css generated.

I tried to create a new Laravel project on another computer and running `npm run dev` on it works without a problem. Both run on Windows 10, node version v10.16.0, npm version 6.9.0.

I tried to completely reinstall Node (to latest 10.16.0) and create a new Laravel project from scratch but with no luck.

Comment: Do you mean it does not emit CSS? If so please reword the title.

Comment: What do the contents of your webpack.mix.js file look like? And in your package.json do you have "cross-env": "^5.1" and "laravel-mix": "^4.0.16"?

Comment: Hi @KarlHill, my webpack.mix.js is without any change after Laraval install: ```const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
``` and in package.json `"cross-env": "^5.1",  "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7"`. Same as on second computer, where everything is running OK.

Comment: Sounds bizarre. A new version of Laravel Mix came out today. Do an 'npm update' command, and it should update all your libraries, specifically + laravel-mix@4.1.2. Then try 'npm run prod' to see if there's any effect mainly that your app.css gets emitted to the '/public/css/app.css' path.

Comment: Didn't help. Only app.js and fontawesome fonts has been emmited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finaly solved it. The problem was that I have my workspace located on `D:\www` and symlinked to my `C:\Users\ondra\www` directory. If I start `npm run dev` from the original location `D:\www\project`, everything works OK. Why it is not working from symlinked `C:\Users\ondra\www\project` is a mistery for me :)

Comment: Thank the lord, indeed this was it for me!

Answer (score 0):

another solution for this is changing the webpack.mix.js file and adding the full path for the scss source files , for example:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js') .sass('/home/ewertonvaz/laravelapp/resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Note that if you are using Windows you have to remove drive letter reference and the path name must be written with double slash.